# Difference between offloading decision and task scheduling in context of fog computing

Tags: cloud, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, fog, offloading

In context of fog computing, the computation offloading decision decides where to offload- on cloud or on fog or execute it locally. While task scheduling also decides where to execute task on fog or on cloud. Then what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

The computation offloading decision decides where to offload - to cloud or fog (or whichever another middleware technology is in place). On the other hand, task scheduling refers to the algorithm used to execute the received task, such as Random, Shortest-Job First (SJF), Longest-Job First (LJF), so on.

Answer (score 0):

Offloading generally refers to sending a part of a job to some  remote computing resource.

Task scheduler mainly produces a schedule for a set of tasks. It may produce a schedule which is local, remote or hybrid.

When referring to Offloading, we are concerned with effective measures to reduce computation energy or to reduce latency.

To meet this, we can create a schedule using task scheduler.